# selection sort with generics

Tags: java, generics, primitive

I did selection sort with integers and it was working, when I tried to modify the program to work with generics the compiler is complaining and I don't know how to fix it. If anyone can point some tips and constructive comments I would be grateful. Here is the code.

```
public class SelelctionSort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] list = {34, 17, 23, 35, 45, 9, 1};
        System.out.println("Original Array: ");
        printArray(list);

        selectionSort(list);
        System.out.println("\nSelection sort:");
        printArray(list);

    }

    //selection sort
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void selectionSort(E[] list)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<list.length -1; i++)
        {
            int iSmallest = i;

            for(int j=i+1; j<list.length; j++)
            {
                if(list[iSmallest].compareTo((list[j])) > 0  )
                {
                    iSmallest = j;
                }
            }
            E iSwap = list[iSmallest];
            list[iSmallest] = list[i];
            list[i] = iSwap;

        }
    }

    public static <E> void printArray(E[] list)
    {

        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(list[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

The following is what `javac` spits out.

> ```
> SelelctionSort.java:7: error: method printArray in class SelelctionSort cannot be applied to given types;
>         printArray(list);
>         ^
>   required: E[]
>   found: int[]
>   reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
>     inferred: int
>     bound(s): Object
>   where E is a type-variable:
>     E extends Object declared in method <E>printArray(E[])
> SelelctionSort.java:9: error: method selectionSort in class SelelctionSort cannot be applied to given types;
>         selectionSort(list);
>         ^
>   required: E[]
>   found: int[]
>   reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
>     inferred: int
>     bound(s): Comparable<int>
>   where E is a type-variable:
>     E extends Comparable<E> declared in method <E>selectionSort(E[])
> SelelctionSort.java:11: error: method printArray in class SelelctionSort cannot be applied to given types;
>         printArray(list);
>         ^
>   required: E[]
>   found: int[]
>   reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
>     inferred: int
>     bound(s): Object
>   where E is a type-variable:
>     E extends Object declared in method <E>printArray(E[])
> ```

Comment: What is the compiler saying to you?

Comment: `int` does not extend `Object`

Comment: The message is:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method printArray(E[]) in the type SelelctionSort is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
 The method selectionSort(E[]) in the type SelelctionSort is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
 The method printArray(E[]) in the type SelelctionSort is not applicable for the arguments (int[])

 at SelelctionSort.main(SelelctionSort.java:8)

Comment: I have tried with an array with Object but the compiler is complaining with: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Bound mismatch: The generic method selectionSort(E[]) of type SelelctionSort is not applicable for the arguments (Object[]). The inferred type Object is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<E>>

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter try `Integer[] list = {34, 17, 23, 35, 45, 9, 1};` The runtime errors are because Eclipse is bad and compiles code that is invalid. Using `javac` won't let it compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] list = {34, 17, 23, 35, 45, 9, 1};
...
selectionSort(list);
```

You are trying to call `selectionSort()` which signature is `selectionSort(E[])`, but `int` does not extend `Comparable` (It is a [primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), not even an object) - and thus the types are not matching.

You can try to create an `Integer[]` and pass it. [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is an object and it extends `Comparable<Integer>`.

The alternative is to **overload** `selectionSort()` to accept both generic type for objects and to overload it for each needed primitive. This is the solution java uses for its [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) method.

The same holds for `printArray()`

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter: I editted the answer - if you want to use primitive (which is often the case) you can *overload* the method. This is the solution java uses for its `sort()`

Answer (score 1):

As said above you are using `selectionSort(E[])` where E extends Comparable means , your selection sort can take the argument who implemented the Comparable interface. As int is primitive data so it's giving the compilation Error. So if you want generic feature then you can use Wrapper classes, All wrapper classes implemented the Comparable interface. The below code will work, Just edit version of your code

```
public class SelelctionSort 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Integer[] list = {34, 17, 23, 35, 45, 9, 1};
    System.out.println("Original Array: ");
    printArray(list);

    selectionSort(list);
    System.out.println("\nSelection sort:");
    printArray(list);
    Float[] flist = {34.4f, 17.6f, 23.0f};
    selectionSort(list);
}

//selection sort
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void selectionSort(E[] list)
{
    for(int i=0; i<list.length -1; i++)
    {
        int iSmallest = i;

        for(int j=i+1; j<list.length; j++)
        {
            if(list[iSmallest].compareTo((list[j])) > 0  )
            {
                iSmallest = j;
            }
        }
        E iSwap = list[iSmallest];
        list[iSmallest] = list[i];
        list[i] = iSwap;

    }
}

public static <E> void printArray(E[] list)
{

    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(list[i] + ", ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it is really working 
this solution is working with all types of variables
and as i m passing the String variable it is showing error